# Redshift SQL: Is there a difference between `=` and `is` for boolean values?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

In aws Redshift, is there a difference between `boolean_column = true` and `boolean_column IS true`?

The docs recommend "always checking Boolean values explicitly" https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Boolean_type.html

I have a redshift table with three boolean columns. The following query runs without error and returns the expected result (i.e. `my_any_column` is `true` if any of the three columns is true):

```
-- Does work
SELECT
    (
        boolean_column_01 = true
        OR boolean_column_02 = true
        OR boolean_column_03 = true
    ) AS my_any_column
FROM
    my_example_table;
```

However, if I change the query as follows, there is an error:

```
-- Does not work
SELECT
    (
        boolean_column_01 is true
        OR boolean_column_02 is true
        OR boolean_column_03 is true
    ) AS my_any_column
FROM
    my_example_table;
```

This is the error message of the query using `is`:

```
SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: Assert
  Detail:
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Assert
  code:      1000
  context:   arg_func_info.is_nullable_ == fld->a_nullable() - arg_func_info.is_nullable_=0, fld->a_nullable()=1.
  query:     1008428
  location:  cg_expr_fn_builder.cpp:8993
  process:   padbmaster [pid=4919]
  -----------------------------------------------
```

The weirdest thing is that the following query does work without error:

```
-- Does work
SELECT
    (
        boolean_column_01 is true
        OR boolean_column_02 is true
        OR boolean_column_03 = true
    ) AS my_any_column
FROM
    my_example_table;
```

With 2 * `is` and 1 * `=` the query works (irrespective of the order), but as soon as there are 3 * `is` it fails.

As a workaround I can simply always use `=` instead of `is`, <s>but I cannot find such a recommendation in the docs.</s>

Comment: often you added characters, that aren't displayed and cause trouble, i usually copy the text into a text editor and switch to hex, to see if there is something wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IS true and = are not equivalent in Redshift.  Per the Redshift docs

"You can use an IS comparison to check a Boolean value only as a predicate in the WHERE clause. You can't use the IS comparison with a Boolean value in the SELECT list."

See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Boolean_type.html (Yes this is the same page you linked)

As you likely expected this is (in part) due to the handling of NULLs.  Conditions in the Redshift use trinary (three-valued) logic (true, false, unknown) and by performing an "IS" comparison the logic moves back to binary.  Binary is better understood by most and thus explicit checks lead to fewer bugs (it is also clearer to those reading the code).  See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_logical_condition.html

Comment: in the examples is a version where it is checked `IS true`, so the code is valid as  it is

Comment: You mean the example that says "The following example returns an error because it uses an IS comparison in the SELECT list."?  And the example shows the error message "[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Not implemented"?

Comment: no i mean the one that says '`In this example, the query selects users from the USERS table who like sports but do not like theatre: '`

Comment: Oh the example that has the "is true" in the WHERE clause which the documentation says is ok.  The question is about "is true" in the SELECT clause which the documentation says is not allowed.

Comment: @BillWeiner thank you. I had totally overlooked "You can't use the IS comparison with a Boolean value in the SELECT list." in the docs. So `boolean_column is true` uses boolean logic, and `boolean_column = true` uses ternary logic? Wouldn't it make sense to generally use `=`, also in the `where` clause, if working with data that has `true`, `false`, and `null`?

Comment: They are different - NULL = true produces NULL but NULL is true produces is false.  The value of "is true" is to remove the 3rd result option of NULL in a WHERE clause.  This doesn't seem like a big deal in the simple case but when complex logic trees are involved where 1 input can be NULL this can simplify a ton of debug.  "Not (NULL OR false ) = true" is false but "Not (NULL OR false) is true" is true.  (see - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/fc1f8/15)  This is why the docs say to simplify your boolean logic and use "is true"  as many get with trinary values.